# SQL to retrieve aggregated data with computed columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table that looks like this for about ~30 students:

```
StudentID    Course*      CourseStatus
1            Math         Pass
1            English      Fail
1            Science      Pass
2            Math         Fail
2            English      Pass
2            Science      Fail
etc.
```

*In my actual database the 'Course' column is a CourseID e.g. (1 = Math; 2 = English etc.) which references a 'CourseName' table. I amended the table above just to make it clear the nature of the problem.

I want to write a query (stored procedure) in SQL that summarises performance for a given course and returns the following:

```
EXEC usp_GetCourseSummary 'Math'

Total Students     Total Pass    % Pass    Total Fail    % Fail
25                 15            60        10            40
```

Have been scratching my head on this one for some time. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand. The first number is presumably the number of distinct students. Why is the sum of passes + fails = number of students? Each student can pass or fail mutliple courses, so I'd expect the totals to be different. Can you post the answer you'd expect for the actual example data that you've given us (just those 6 rows).

Comment: @Mark. As an example, there are 30 students and they all do Math. Any given student can either fail or pass. So for 'Math' I'd expect something like: Total Students = 30; Total Pass = 20; % Pass = 66%; Total Fail = 10; % Fail = 33%.

Comment: Oh, yes sorry, my fault. I missed that there is a parameter on your stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetCourseSummary
    @Course nvarchar(100)
AS     
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT
        COUNT(StudentId) AS [Total Students],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CourseStatus = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Pass],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CourseStatus = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(*) AS [% Pass],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CourseStatus = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Fail], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN CourseStatus = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(*) AS [% Fail]
    FROM table1
    WHERE Course = @Course;
GO

EXEC usp_GetCourseSummary 'Math'
```

Result:

```
Total Students  Total Pass  % Pass  Total Fail  % Fail
2               1           50      1           50
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (StudentID INT NOT NULL, Course NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, CourseStatus NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Table1 (StudentID, Course, CourseStatus) VALUES
(1, 'Math', 'Pass'),
(1, 'English', 'Fail'),
(1, 'Science', 'Pass'),
(2, 'Math', 'Fail'),
(2, 'English', 'Pass'),
(2, 'Science', 'Fail');
```

Comment: @Mark: This looks good and I'll give it a try later on today but I am sure I can use this. Incidentally, whilst trying to solve this problem I had been perusing 'SQL for Smarties' by Celko and had been wondering whether using CASE statements would work. Obviously I need to pay more attention!

Comment: @Mark: I have now tried this and it worked perfectly. Your approach has helped me re-evalaute other stored procedures I have been using so thanks for pushing me in the right direction. Much appreciated and thanks for your time.